# what is the Google map client side geocodding limitation on mobile devices?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

As per google documentation if i use client side geocodding then i can make 2500 request per client devise.

I have implemented client side reverse geocodding in my mobile application. below is the code for the same.

```
count = 0;
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.1819936,72.83240448",
async: true,
success: function(result){
             console.log(result);
         }});

}, 2000);
```

But the problem is that even after making more than 2500 request on each mobile device, Google is not giving me any "quota limit" error.

So my question is does this mean that client side geocodding limitation is not applicable to mobile device??

Answer (score 0):

[Client-side geocoding through the browser is rate limited per map session, so the geocoding is distributed across all your users and scales with your userbase.](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits) It is possible that the Android Geocoder has [different limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218764/android-geocoder-quota-limits) though. It sounds like the limits may be similar, but not strictly enforced.