# Geocoder API usage limit query

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Geocoder "getFromLocation" API provided as part of Google SDK in my Android application (Link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get location address details. The input parameters fed to this API are latitude, longitude which are obtained from "getLastKnownLocation" API of Location Manager.

I would like to know if there is any API usage limit per day for Geocoder "getFromLocation" API provided by Google as this API does not ask for any API KEY?

Any input on this will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: The Geocoder "getFromLocation" is not from Google Maps API so you don't need any API key for that.

Comment: If you check [Geocoder getFromLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation) , nowhere does it state that there's limit usage for that call. So I think you'll do just fine using that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Will update if I observe any changes with respect to what we have discussed.

Comment: @abhat From your observations did you find any limit for this? I am also using same and want to know is there any limit?

Comment: @shylendra any update on android geocoder usage limit policy? Do you get reverse geocoded results on every attempt?

Comment: @NabeelThobani Yes, we need to enable billing now, AND 50 requests per second (QPS), calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries. source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing

Comment: @shylendra Looks like you have moved to google geocoding api and consuming like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Any idea about usage limit of Geocoder that's mentioned below:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder

Comment: @NabeelThobani as noogui mentioned in the previous comment there is no any limit in using Geocoder getFromLocation. You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782962/2462531